# select account (lookup) through picklist on Flow Designer

Tags: custom-object, flow, visual-workflow, standard-objects

I have a flow designer and it's based off of a custom object with has an account associated to it.  However, I cannot figure out how to select the account through the drop down list.

Whenever, I select Account as a dropdown list, my choices are never the account.

Object:  Account
Field:  is all of the picklist fields on the object.

Is there a way I can pick an account within this flow?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish or what is going wrong. Can you clarify your question and update with eg. screenshots?

Comment: I actually figure it out.  I basically wanted to have a drop down for a lookup field on an object for a flow screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually to do it using this:

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-lookup-field-in-flow/

However, because the picklist was so small for me, I was able to spoof it by creating two variables:  one for the account ID and one for the account name

Then I created dynamic search results based on "NOT EQUAL TO:  asdfasdfsafdds" which gave me all of the results. Added "Name" to choice label and ID to choice stored value.  Then assigned the record fields to variables where ID = accountIDVar, and Name = AccountNameVar.

On my create record step, I simply assigned the var's