# Flow Fast Lookup to Dropdown

Tags: visual-workflow, fast-lookup

I am building a form for users to populate information about competitors. I went with flow so I can page through the different fields that they need to populate. I want to setup a simple search for company names where they type in the name in a text field -> I lookup records that match the sting -> then populate a drop down that they can select the account that matches.

My problem is that although the fast lookup is coming back with results I can't them to populate in the dropdown. I added a text output field so that I can see the results of the search and it comes back with record ids that match. I can't figure out how to set the results as the dropdown variable. What am I doing wrong?

Screen 1 users put in a name

[image: Screen 1]

Fast lookup looks for records where the company name contains the input text.

[image: Fast Lookup]

The dynamic choice is where the results of the lookup should populate as the name.

[image: Dynamic choice]

[image: Screen 2]

In the results it's coming back with the id so it makes me think the fast lookup works but alas, no choices.

[image: results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a youtube video from [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-lookup-field-in-flow/), and some insight from [select account (lookup) through picklist on Flow Designer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115621/select-account-lookup-through-picklist-on-flow-designer)  I was adding an extra step that was not needed. You don't need a fast lookup to get results to display on the screen you just need the two screen, one to input the value and one to display the choices in the dropdown.

I removed the lookup and just went with the screens and it works.